添付ファイルのような「出」に背景色をつけるVBAで作成したい
目的
Excelで当番表を作成する際に、指定された条件に基づいて背景色を公平かつランダムに割り当てるVBAコードを作成したいです。（作成前は「出」の背景色がない状態です）
詳細は以下の通りです。
シート構成:
列に日付が記載されています。
行には名前が記載されています。
「出」と書かれたセルのみが有効です。（「休」などは無視）
背景色の割り当て:
選択セルと同じ背景色を使って、範囲選択内、1日あたりn名割り当てるかを指定する。（nはメッセージボックスにてその都度記載）
1日ｎ人は絶対ですが、〇〇さんが月ｎ回行うのは多少の誤差は許容します。
背景色はランダムに割り当てるが、行の割り振りは連日にならないようにする。
背景色の数を把握する:
使用した背景色の数を把握し、その結果をメッセージボックスで表示する。
注意点:（繰り返しになりますが）
・背景色の割り当ては公平であることが重要です。クレームが来てしまいます。
例えば、添付ファイルのように全員なるべく同じ月2回としたい。
誤差で多人は休みの多い人だと尚良いです。
・「出」と書かれたセルのみが対象です（非表示も無視）
・背景色が連続して横並びにならないようにする（土日をはさむ場合も）
この要件に基づいて、適切なVBAコードを作成したいです。
ChatGPTにお任せしようとしたのですが無理でした。
添付したファイルについて
毎日当番3名をランダムで選んでいて、全員月2回という場合です。色は黄色とは限りません。
実際はもっともっと入り組んでいるので、これをチマチマとやっていると2時間作業のためVBA作りたいです(´;ω;｀)
達人の皆様、お助けいただけませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします！
作成前:

期待する結果:




実現したいことに対して、何がわからないのか 、自分なりに途中まででも試したこと等を整理して投稿してください。現状だと仕様が書かれているだけで「誰か代わりに作ってくれ」という内容に見え、それは質問ではなくプログラムの作成依頼です。

「これをチマチマとやっていると2時間作業のためVBA作りたいです(´;ω;｀)」とのことですが、1週間に1回の作業なのか1か月に1回の作業なのか等でも負荷は変わってくるかと思います。文面からはVBAが全く書けないように感じますし「公平」をプログラムに落とし込むのは結構難易度高いかと思います。

どうやって対象を選ぶかは不明ですが、選んだ後の対処はこの辺の記事が参考になるかも。VBAで指定文字列があるセルに背景色を設定する, 【VBA】指定した文字列が設定されているセルの背景色を変更する, Excel VBA セルの文字、背景色を指定する, 【エクセルマクロ】特定文字を含むセルを色分け：select case

ちなみにWindows11のCopilotで月毎のパートタイマーの出勤日割り当てを公平に平均的に行うVBAプログラムのサンプルはありますか？のように質問すると、何かそれらしい回答が出てきましたが、そう言うのを試してみてはどうでしょう？

1日ｎ人は絶対ですが、〇〇さんが月ｎ回行うとはどういうことでしょうか？
誤差とは何の誤差でしょうか？
非表示も無視 ということは、非表示の「出」のセルがあるということですね？
全体に良くわからないのですが、Excel ということは別にして下記のようなことをやりたいのでしょうか？
曜日に関係なく毎日ｎ人交代で例えば掃除当番をする。
ｎ人は下記の条件で選択する。
● 「出」の人が対象
● 前日対象になった人は対象外（前月末は？）
● 各人の前日まで対象になった日数が少ない人から選択する。
● 「出」の日数が少ない人は優先的に選択する？
● 「出」の対象の人がｎ人いなかった場合は「絶対」ということなのでエラーにするのでしょうか？
「ランダムに割り当てる」ということは、上記のようには決められないかな？
仕様が良くわからないのでアルゴリズムが組み立てられません。
追記）
おかめ さん
私はコメントを付けられないようなのでここに追記します。
VBAを画像で添付されましたが、私は目が悪くてわかりずらいので、テキストにしてもらえませんか
編集時に上に表示されている「コード」をクリックすると説明が表示されます。
全ての行の先頭に空白を４文字追加すれば良いです。
上に空行が必要なようです。
Excel の VB Editorで行を選択して{TAB}キーを押すと空白が４文字追加されるので試してみてください。
文章の下のプレビューで確認すると縦横スクロール付きのボックスで表示されます。
例
Sub test1()
    AssignEmployee ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P17"), 3
End Sub


ご回答ありがとうございます。
人は50名～60名いて変動するので、最高100人対応できるようにしたいです。「出」の対象がいなければエラーにします。先頭のセルが無色だったらエラーにします。前日対象になった人は対象外にしたいです。前月末は無視します。
それでつくってみたVBAを添付します（半分逆さになってしまいましたが）これで思った通りに動きましたが、もっとこうした方が良いよ！というのがあれば教えていただけるとうれしいですm(__)m

曜日に関係なく毎日ｎ人交代で例えば掃除当番をする。
そうです！曜日関係なく「出」と書かれているセルに対してのみ当番を割り振ることがしたいです。
電話当番なんですけどね(^^)/

1日ｎ人は絶対ですが、〇〇さんが月ｎ回行うとはどういうことでしょうか？
例えば1日6人は絶対に割り振りたいのですが、人単位で見ますとどうしても月5回の人もいれば月6回の人が出てくるということです。誤差とは1人1人が月何回回ってくるか？の誤差です。一人が4回で1人が2回だとクレームが来てしまいます。。なので誤差はできるだけ1にとどめたいです。
